# Shell Script Error : " [: too many arguments"

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a small script where i have to check whether particular process is running or not? and then according to that i have to take action. **And Yes shell is bash.**

To Check process is running or not?  [From This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708715/check-if-program-is-running-with-bash-shell-script)  I tried,

```
 Process_Num='ps -ef | grep /opt/sro/bin/srocmsd | grep -v "grep" | wc -l'
 if [ $Process_Num -eq 1 ]
 then
      ***Do Stuff***
 else
      ***Do Stuff***
 fi
```

but i am getting error :

```
**Error  : line 191: [: too many arguments**
```

While running the same command directly on shell/terminal i am getting output as 1.

Is there any syntax error? Can any1 help?

Comment: If you'd copied the answer you linked correctly, you'd know Process_Num is just a string, not actually evaluated

Answer (score 5):

To put the result of command execution in an environment variable you should put the command in backquotes (`) or use `$(command)` syntax:

```
 Process_Num=$(ps -ef | grep /opt/sro/bin/srocmsd | grep -v "grep" | wc -l)
```

Comment: Yes, Working :) Thank you

Comment: btw, the answer to the question that you linked give exactly the same advice ;)

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant to use back quotes here:

```
Process_Num='ps -ef | grep /opt/sro/bin/srocmsd | grep -v "grep" | wc -l'
```

i.e.

```
Process_Num=`ps -ef | grep /opt/sro/bin/srocmsd | grep -v "grep" | wc -l`
            ^                                                           ^
```

Comment: Yes, Working... Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need to make it so complicated by calling `grep` twice and then `wc -l` to count the lines and putting whole thing in *command substitution*.

You can just use `grep -q` to get the exit status of `grep`:

```
if ps cax | grep -Fq 'srocmsd'
then
     echo "found matching process"
else
     echo "Didn't find matching process"
fi
```

Comment: This has the distinct problem that it is somewhat likely that `grep` will match itself. This is an age-old FAQ which does not need to be answered again, anyway.

Comment: `grep -q '[s]rocmsd'` to ensure `grep` doesn't match itself but due to use of `-c` option in `ps` which prints only the **executable name** this problem won't come.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Your attempted fix would need to drop the `-F` flag, though.

Comment: Ah, yes that's right otherwise `[` and `]` will be literal :)