# If command condition at runtime shell

Tags: shell

I want to write shell script which allows me to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if ( when "pbpaste" command has been launched by user )
then
do something
fi
```

Comment: Do you want your `if` statement to run in response to `pbpaste` being run by the user every time, or only run if a `pbpaste` process is running?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if program is running with bash shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708715/check-if-program-is-running-with-bash-shell-script)

Answer (score 0):

Replace pbpaste by your own version, which first does *something*, and then invoke the original pbpaste.