# How to check whether my process is running or not in Linux

Tags: linux, shell

I'm running a script called RecordProcessor.sh and I'm writing another script to check whether RecordProcessor.sh is running or not.Even though  that process is running, if i do grep I'm not able to find the process running .

My script is as follows:

```
ps -U $LOGNAME | grep "RecordProcessor.sh"
```

I did everything even like

```
ps -U $LOGNAME | grep -v grep | grep "RecordProcessor.sh"
```

I can only find in which bash it is running not the actual file name.

Comment: Run your script. Then type `mypid=$$` (as the very next command). That will save the process ID for your script in `mypid`. Then check if it is running with `ps $mypic`.

Comment: What about using a supervisor, you could use for example immortal and run only once your script and restart if required: https://immortal.run/post/retries/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux command to check if a shell script is running or not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16828035/608639), [How to check if another instance of my shell script is running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16807876/608639), [Linux/Unix command to determine if process is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9117507/608639), [Check if program is running with bash shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7708715/608639), [Check if a process is running using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29260576/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
if pidof -s RecordProcessor.sh &>/dev/null;then 
   echo "process exists"
else
   echo "no such process"
fi
```

Or using grep

```
if ps -aux -U $LOGNAME | grep RecordProcessor.sh |  grep --quiet -v "grep";then 
   echo "process exists"
else
   echo "no such process"
fi
```

Comment: Even though I'm running that process I'm getting No such process. I dont know why

Comment: While that would be right if `RecordProcessor.sh` was being run directly, here it is the argument for `grep "RecordProcessor.sh"`

Comment: Hey mik1904,even though I'm running your script and RecordProcessor.sh is also running i'm getting output as "no such process".

Comment: @AnirudhS How do you know RecordProcessor.sh is running

Comment: RecordProcessor.sh is running in a infinite loop

Comment: Use `flock` to run RecordProcessor.sh, then check if your selected pid file exists on disk. See : https://linux.die.net/man/1/flock

Comment: @AnirudhS I have reasons to believe your process is not running. Please double check.

Comment: @mik1904 Thanks for your replies.Calumah your answer helped me and when I run my script using flock it's working properly thanks.